# Replace any number of tabs and spaces with single new line in Linux?

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting, tr, whitespace

Suppose I have a (potentially very large) text file
that contains a word list with whitespace interjected. 
For example, it might look like this:

```
Cat                           Dog
Soup                          Rat
Cass                          Audrey
```

I want each word on a separate line (with no whitespace), like this:

```
Cat
Dog
Soup
Rat
Cass
Audrey
```

I can do a simple `tr -d " "` to make that into:

```
CatDog
SoupRat
CassAudrey
```

(but that is not what I want).

I do not know what type of blank space separates those words,
so assume that it's some combination of ordinary ASCII spaces and tabs. 
(We can assume that there are no invisible Unicode characters
like em spaces and zero-width thingies.) 
Naturally, the words do not *contain* whitespace, so "à la",
"alma mater", "apple pie", "at large" and "ice cream"
are not valid words.

Assume that words may contain (non-blank) non-alphabetic characters,
such as "AC/DC", "add-on", "AT&T", "audio-visual",
"can't", "carbon-14", "jack-o'-lantern", "mother-in-law",
"o'clock", "O'Reilly", "RS-232" and "3-D". 
Ideally the solution should tolerate non-ASCII characters,
as in "Ångström", "Gödel", "naïve", "résumé" and "smörgåsbord".

How do I get rid of all those spaces while preserving (and isolating)
the indented words using common Unix/Linux tools like `tr`, `sed` or `awk`?

It would be great if the solution would also work
for more general cases of the stated problem;
i.e., not just two-column text, but also random arrangements like:

```
          Once    upon
    a   midnight
                    dreary
while                     I pondered
       weak    and weary
           Over                many
a   quaint  and     curious     volume
 of forgotten lore
```

Comment: `set -f; printf ‘%s\n’ $(<file); set +f`. This is halfway a joke, because there are other types of expansion in the shell besides globs, but in some hackish cases it might be a very simple solution.

Comment: This is not a question "describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed)". This question describes a reproducible problem, whose solution(s) *are likely* to help future readers.  The fact that the OP didn't *actually **have** the problem* they described does not invalidate the question, *per se.*

Comment: @G-Man it looks to me like the OP said in version 3 that "So it was looking like some words were appearing right-justified. I went through the same file more slowly with vim and there were no right-justified words." which sounds to me like they realized that there wasn't actually a problem to solve. If we want to reopen this question for the existing answers, I'd suggest editing the Q down to focus on the problem that they solve.

Comment: @Jeff: Well, I acknowledged that "the OP didn't *actually **have** the problem* they described".  So, what, exactly, are you suggesting?  That I delete the OP's edit (i.e., the last paragraph)?  Or should I purge all references to the “back story” of how a person might land in the situation of having a file like the one described in the question?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I personally think we should keep this question closed, since the OP is in no position to accept an answer. I'll abstain from voting in the reopen queue, though. If we think that this is the best question we have on removing spaces, then I would say to edit the Q to focus on that, removing the backstory and "I didn't actually have this problem" parts.

Answer (score 14):

etopylight was almost right:

```
tr -s ' \t' '\n'
```

because the question asks to replace tabs, too.

Comment: The POSIX equivalent would be `tr -s ' \t' '[\n*]'`. See also `tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]'` or `tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]'`

Comment: This fails on `"AC/DC", "add-on", "AT&T"`. You need something like `tr -s ' \t,."' '\n' <file`

Comment: @Isaac Well, that’s debatable. The question says, “Assume that words may ***contain*** (non-blank) ***non-alphabetic characters***”. (Disclosure: I edited the question to say that, with the intent of *keeping* my answer correct.) If words may contain non-alphabetic characters, then "AC/DC", "add-on" and  "AT&T" are all words. And the OP didn’t give us any clue how they want “Mr.”, “Mrs.”, “Ph.D” or “Q.E.D.” to be handled. While comma (and semicolon) maybe should always be separators, people with 20th century technology sometimes used `"` to denote umlaut / dieresis; e.g., `na"ive` for `naïve`.

Comment: Fair enough. @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'

Comment: That would output a blank line at the start of the OPs 2nd set of input (the one that starts with spaces).

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you could do it in GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'
```

There you go...

Comment: That would output multiple blank lines given the OPs 2nd set of input (the one that starts with spaces).

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\n/'
```

to replace any sequence of one or more whitespace characters (including oddities like formfeed and vertical tabs) with a single newline.

Comment: Almost portable, but most `sed` versions will insert a backslash and an `n`, because `\n` in the replacement is undefined by the standard. Use a literal newline instead (typically by typing backslash, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-J).

Comment: That would output multiple blank lines and lines containing spaces given the OPs 2nd set of input (the one that starts with spaces).

Answer (score 2):

If gnu-grep available,

```
grep -Po '\S+'
```

Comment: That would work, though you don't need `-P` (which even in new versions of GNU grep is still considered "experimental" in combination with other grep options so I personally avoid), it'd work the same with `-E`.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in a long list of ways:

[tr](/questions/tagged/tr) `tr -s  ' \t'       '\n'   <file`                 for tabs and spaces only.
[tr](/questions/tagged/tr) `tr -s  ' \t,."'    '\n'   <file`                 for your strings.
[tr](/questions/tagged/tr) `tr -s  '[:blank:]' '\n'   <file`                 for tabs and spaces only.
[tr](/questions/tagged/tr) `tr -s  '[:space:]' '\n'   <file`                 for `\t\n\v\f\r` 
[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `sed -e 's/[ \t]/\n/g' -e 's/\n\n*/\n/g' file`    GNU sed for `\n`.
[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `sed 's/[ \t".,]\+/\n/g'  file | tr -s '\n'`      GNU sed for `\n`.

---

## Description

### tr

The most basic tool is `tr`, yes, but it could not understand format.
So, a basic

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <file
```

would convert all (repeated) spaces to **one** newline. That, of course could generate empty lines if lines with only spaces exist or the file start with spaces. There is no way to correct that in `tr`. It could be done adding a filter to remove empty lines. Like `sed '/^$/d'`

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sed '/^$/d'
```

Additional characters (like tabs) could be added:

```
tr -s ' \t' '\n' <file | sed '/^$/d'
```

Others, that might result from a text paragraph (like this one), like commas and periods could also be added. That is changing the definition of what a word is.

```
tr -s ' \t,.()' '\n' <file | sed '/^$/d'
```

### sed

Sed is more capable than tr (and could be slower). It could change runs of some characters to one newline. The basic idea would be (in GNU sed for the replacement `\n`):

```
sed 's/[ \t]\{1,\}/\n/g'
```

In other seds that are not able to use `\n` in the right side of a replacement we need to use an actual newline (and, sometimes, an actual tab):

```bsh
sed 's/[   ]\{1,\}/\
/g'
```

So, sed helps with some issues but makes unnecessarily complex others.
Read [4.1. How do I insert a newline into the RHS of a substitution?](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.1)

### grep

It could be done in grep as well. Just match sequences of non-word characters:

```bsh
grep -o '[^         ]\{1,\}'     ## explicit space-tab.
```

In GNU grep, the equivalent `\S+` could be used:

```bsh
grep -Eo '\S+'     ## or grep -o '\S\+'
```

### awk

In `awk` we get still more power from the tool. It gets quite simple:

```bsh
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' file
```

Which is just: print all fields for each line. Where there are fields. If the number of fields is 0 nothing will be printed.

That is using the default FS which delimits fields on repeated spaces, tabs or newlines.

A similar solution could be done with `RS` (for awks that allow regex separators):

```bsh
awk -v RS="[ \t\n]+" 'NF'
```

Which tells awk to split records in runs of space, tab or newlines and print only if there is any no-empty field (the NF).

Comment: I believe all of those would output a blank line at the start of the OPs 2nd set of input (the one that starts with spaces).

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, technically, that is correct for the initial ways I posted. It is quite simple to remove empty lines, anyway, so, I am not very worried for this issue. However, I extended the description to solve that from different points of view. I believe that I have clarified that issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the default behavior for awk already is to split on any number of blanks (spaces, tabs), one could as well use that feature, just setting the output field separator to "\n" and rebuilding $0. 
An open question for the task, however, is:
How do you want empty lines to be handled?

To just print them as they are:

```
awk -v OFS='\n' '{$1 = $1; print}' file
```

To additionally filter out empty lines:

```
awk -v OFS='\n' 'NF {$1 = $1; print}' file
```

(Beware of Windows line endings (containing \r) in a Linux setting, however:
awk does not necessarily regard lines with \r as empty and in that case would output them too. 
So filter text files with CRLF endings through `dos2unix` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `-s` from `tr` to squeeze repeated characters into one and replace it into a new line

```
tr -s " " "\n"
```

Comment: That wouldn't handle tabs in the input and would output a blank line at the start of the OPs 2nd set of input (the one that starts with spaces).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk or any other awk that supports multi-char RS (e.g. newer versions of mawk):

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '$0!=""' file
Cat
Dog
Soup
Rat
Cass
Audrey
```

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '$0!=""' file2
Once
upon
a
midnight
dreary
while
I
pondered
weak
and
weary
Over
many
a
quaint
and
curious
volume
of
forgotten
lore
```

Comment: Should `awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NF' file2` not work ?

Comment: @ImHere yes, I think that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Simple optimal text formatter displays in one column with further deletion of leading spaces:

```bsh
fmt -1 file | column -t
```

In awk `NF` prevents from possible output of the first empty line:

```
awk 'NF' RS='[[:space:]]+' file
```